# Is it possible to place a firebase query inside a widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I want to fetch firebase data and show it in a image slider.I have attached my code. Currently i a passing some asset images. The requirement is to fetch the images from Firebase and show it in the slider.
Could anyone please let me know how can i do this.

```
  Widget image_slider_carousel = Container(

      height: 250,
      child: Carousel(
        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
        images: [
          AssetImage('images/abc.jpg'),
          AssetImage('images/abc.jpg'),
          AssetImage('images/abc.jpg'),
          AssetImage('images/abc.jpg'),
          AssetImage('images/abc.jpg'),



        ],
      ),

    );


return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.red.withGreen(10),
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
              child: Text('KartOfill',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),

              ),

            ),
            titleSpacing: 50.0,
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Container(
              height: 1350,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[

                  image_slider_carousel, //// image carousel Widget
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zkzQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `FutureBuilder` to get the URLs and use `NetworkImage()` instead of `AssetImage()`, like so:

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  future: Firestore.instance.collection("AllimageSlider").getDocuments(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.data != null)
      return Text("No Data!);
    else {
      List _docs = snapshot.data.documents;
      List<NetworkImage> _imgs = List();
      for(int i=0;i<_docs.length;i++)
        _imgs.add(new NetworkImage(_docs[i]["imageUrl"]));
      return Carousel(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        images: _imgs,
      );
    }
  },
)
```

I'm pretty sure there's a better method to generate the `_imgs` List using something like `.forEach()`, and I've forgotten how to use it.

Check that out too.

Comment: How can I get the current index of the image clicked

Comment: Oh for that, just remove the images and place it under a widget instead. Use the ```items``` property for that one. Look up the docs, you'll find your answer there.